# How to retrieve data from a nested node in firebase

Tags: android

I want to retrieve data under a node I've named "Likes" and then inside it I'm storing a "postID" (which also happens to be the key to a post) and a child "UID" which contains all the data I'm trying to retrieve.

I've tried to follow this tutorial but didn't succeed.
[Android Firebase retrieve data from all nodes (nested) in Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44771378/android-firebase-retrieve-data-from-all-nodes-nested-in-fragments)

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes");


        mQuery = databaseReference.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(current_user);
 protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();


        Toast.makeText(this, house+ " "+mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        final String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FavHelper, FavouriteActivity.FavViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FavHelper, FavouriteActivity.FavViewHolder>(FavHelper.class, R.layout.favourite_item, FavouriteActivity.FavViewHolder.class, mQuery) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final FavouriteActivity.FavViewHolder viewHolder, FavHelper model, int position) {



                final String house_id = getRef(position).getKey();

                //if (house_id != null) {
                viewHolder.setPrice(model.getPrice());
                viewHolder.setPlace(model.getPlace());
                viewHolder.setLocation(model.getLocation());
                viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getImage());

                viewHolder.setFavBtn(house_id);




        }
```

I want to show those posts that only the user has liked.[find the pic of the database here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGtIs.png)

Comment: Are you not retrieving any data? Your question seems unclear.

Comment: I'm not getting any data back

Comment: what's your database structure look like?

Comment: I've put the url  in the question

Comment: remove orderbyChild().equalTo() and replace it with orderbyKey() try that.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: i didn't realize this but you're using the adapter wrong. you need to call     adapter.startListening(); onStart(); i would move everying else out of onstart() though and move it to onCreate() look at the documentation. https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md

Comment: I dont think that's the problem because I have the same code in another activity and it's working fine. I think the problem is that I'm not getting the reference to the pushed key right

Comment: then where are you calling firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();

Comment: I'm not callin startListening() anywhere. I can tell the code is working because when I store the data in child("Likes").child(user_id) , the  data gets retrieved successfully.

Comment: Are you using AutomaticListening?

Comment: yeah. How do I reference the push key using the database reference?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing how the data is stored i.e. instead of storing it under

> `.child(house_id).child(user_id)`, I used `.child(user_id).child(house_id)`. but now I have encountered a problem, When I try to save multiple data, it replaces existing ones instead of adding. [Screenshot of the app[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaqSm.png) What I'm I doing wrong?

my code:

```
 viewHolder.favBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mProcessLike = true;

                            mDatabaseLikes.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                    if (mProcessLike) {
                                        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                                            String user = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                                            if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(user) ) {
                                                mDatabaseLikes.child(user).child(house_id).removeValue();
                                                mProcessLike = false;

                                            } else {


                                                KejaHelper keja = new KejaHelper(getApplicationContext());
                                                TextView loc = findViewById(R.id.txtLocation);
                                                TextView place = findViewById(R.id.txtPlace);
                                                TextView price = findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
                                                TextView img = findViewById(R.id.txtKey);
                                            //    String imag = keja.getImage().toString();


                                                dataSnapshot.getValue();


                                                HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                                                map.put("name", loc.getText().toString());
                                                map.put("place", place.getText().toString());
                                                map.put("price",price.getText().toString());
                                                map.put("image",img.getText().toString());
                                                map.put("fav", "love");




                                                mDatabaseLikes.child(user).child(house_id).updateChildren(map);
                                               // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                mProcessLike = false;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
enter code here
enter code here
```